# how to get properties within subsections of a ini file with boost property tree?

Tags: boost, ini, boost-propertytree

I am trying to use the Boost property trees to read `INI`files containing properties within sections have a "composed" path name.

For example my `INI`file looks like this:

```
[my.section.subsection1]
someProp1=0

[my.section.subsection2]
anotherProp=1
```

I read it with the following code:

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

pt::ptree propTree;
pt::read_ini(filePath, propTree);
boost::optional<uint32_t> someProp1 = pt.get_optional<uint32_t>("my.section.subsection1.someProp1");
```

The problem is that I never get the value of `someProp1`...

When I iterate over the first tree level I see the the entire section name `my.section.subsection1` as a key. Is there a way to make the `read_ini` function to parse section names with dots as a tree hierarchy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the property tree to reflect the hierarchy, then it requires writing a custom parser.  Per the INI parser [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.ini_parser):

> INI is a simple key-value format with a single level of sectioning. [...] not all property trees can be serialized as INI files.

Because of the single level sectioning, `my.section.subsection1` must be treated as a key, rather than a hierarchy path.  For example, the `my.section.subsection1.someProp1` path could be broken down into:

```
           key    separator  value 
 .----------^---------. ^ .---^---.
|my.section.subsection1|.|someProp1|
```

Because "." is part of the key, the [`boost::property_tree::string_path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/string_path.html) type must be explicitly instantiated with a different separator.  It is available as a `path_type` typedef on `ptree`.  In this case, I have opted to use "/":

```
 ptree::path_type("my.section.subsection1/someProp1", '/')
```

---

With example.ini containing:

```
[my.section.subsection1]
someProp1=0

[my.section.subsection2]
anotherProp=1
```

The following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
  pt::ptree propTree;

  read_ini("example.ini", propTree);

  boost::optional<uint32_t> someProp1 = propTree.get_optional<uint32_t>(
    pt::ptree::path_type( "my.section.subsection1/someProp1", '/'));
  boost::optional<uint32_t> anotherProp = propTree.get_optional<uint32_t>(
    pt::ptree::path_type( "my.section.subsection2/anotherProp", '/'));
  std::cout << "someProp1 = " << *someProp1 
          << "\nanotherProp = " << *anotherProp
          << std::endl;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
someProp1 = 0
anotherProp = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. Is it (easily) possible to extend the default INI parser to be able to reflect hierarchy based on section names?

Comment: @greydet: I only briefly looked at the parser code, but it did not seem overly complicated.  Another option is to ignore parsing, and instead be able to expand and/or flatten a single level `ptree` to/from a hierarchical `ptree`.